# does gluLookAt has impact on glRotate/glTranslate/glScale?

Tags: opengl, glulookat

I have following code :

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 20.0);
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) 45, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRectf(-1,-1,1,1);
```

the rectangle will be rotated around y-axis. As my result shows, it is still at the center of my window.
But why ?

As I know, the function `gluLookAt` modified MODELVIEW matrix and it issues calls to `glTranslate` inside, so whtat's the exactly behavior of the above `glRotatef` call? why the rotation radius is not 10? (10 is the 3rd param passed to gluLookAt)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does gluLookAt work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166135/how-does-glulookat-work)

Comment: thanks, i didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the reason why my object couldn't self-rotate when I saw you code. In my code, I put **`glRotatef`** before **`gluLookAt`**, which is the only difference from you code. I tried to change the order and it started to self-rotate. Try to change the order of two functions in your code and see what it looks like. I don't really know the reason. Hope someone can explain it.