# from glLookAt() to glRotatef() and gltranslatef

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation

I need to replace the `gluLookAt()` operate by `glRotatef()` and `glTranslatef()` operations.
I mange to do that with `gluLookAt(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0);` but I just guessed some number utill i got the same picture.

what is the math behind that? how can i take some random `gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upZ, upY, upZ)` and change it to rotate and translate and get the same picture?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166135/how-does-glulookat-work

Comment: You would have to find the x-z and the x-y plane angles and individually rotate your matrix by them. Don't forget to first translate your matrix by its negative position self so it rotates about itself. After wards you translate it back.

Comment: @Cyber what is the A and B on the rotatef? and when i try the translate with the -eye vector i cant even see the object

Answer (score 3):

#### `gluLookAt (...)` sets up the axes and origin of your view-space.

It is far easier, in my opinion, to consider what each individual column represents than to turn this operation into a series of translations and rotations (even though fundamentally that is what happens).

To setup the orientation of your view-space, `gluLookAt (...)` basically computes the individual axes. At ***no point*** does it *ever* deal with any Euler angles like `glRotatef (...)` would require you to do. Given the fact that the view-space `gluLookAt (...)` produces is orthogonal, computing the third axis from only two is trivial.

- The Z-axis (forward) is computed as the direction from eye<sub>xyz</sub> to center<sub>xyz</sub>
- The Y-axis (up) is ***given*** directly as up<sub>xyz</sub>
- The X-axis (right) is computed as the ***cross-product*** between the up and forward vectors

These three axes are then stored in columns 1-3 of the matrix, X, Y, Z.

Last, since the viewing transform has position in addition to rotation, the camera's eye point is stored in the 4th column of your matrix.

#### Consider the following diagram from Song Ho Ahn (안성호), [OpenGL Transformation](https://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html):

[image: Axes Diagram]

Honestly, it is more convenient just to setup the matrix yourself instead of dealing with Euler angles and `glRotatef (...)`.

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot figure out why that diagram calls the X-axis left. `gluLookAt (...)` produces a right-handed coordinate system with +Z pointing toward the viewer. +X is therefore right, you can even see this if you look at the actual colored axes. Aside from what you call the X-axis, this diagram should help though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but still i required to the the `gluLookAt()` and translate that to `glRotate()` and `glTranslate()`. forgive me if the answer is there, but i'm kinda new in this field.. if u can provide an answer less complex ill be happy! thanks ahead

Comment: If you thought the answer was complex the way it is, it will be ***much*** more complicated if you use `glRotate (...)` and `glTranslate (...)`. Because then you have to do all of the calculations I just discussed, plus compute the rotation angles from the 3 vectors you *already* have. There is no reason to make this that complicated. The rotation is stored in the upper-left 3x3 sub-matrix, and you can work your way backwards to solve for the rotation angle if you want (as shown [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut06%20Rotation.html)), but it is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andon that finding the whole matrix is much easier. But if you still need to find the decomposition to `glRotate` and `glTranslate`, then you could follow these steps, at least for this specific setting.

[image: Graphical setting]

We need to find a transformation that would convert the representation of a point in the  *xyz* coordinate system into its representation in the *x'y'z'* coordinate system (different from transforming a point). This is the same as aligning the orange system with the blue one.

We can say two things about this transformation:

1. The *y'z'=Uz'* plane is transformed into the *yz* plane.
2. The *z'* axis is transformed into the *z* axis.

To make the transformation we do the following:

1. Translate the origin *E* to point *C*.
2. Rotate around the *y'* axis 90° clockwise to meet condition (2).
3. Rotate around the *z=z'* axis 45° clockwise to meet condition (1).

This can be summed up as:

```
glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-1, -1, 0);
```